# How can I get the form data from the FOSUserBundle registration form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, request, fosuserbundle

I am using the [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) and have overwritten the `RegistrationController`. When the form is submitted and valid, I want to get the email address the user entered in the registration form.

But I don't see any way to get it. As taken from the [Symfony2 forms documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html), you can get form data like this:

```
$this->get('request')->request->get('name');
```

But the `RegistrationController` does not know the `get()` method (as it's not inherited from the Symfony2 controller entity). So I could go like this:

```
// Note the ...->container->...
$this->container->get('request')->request->get('name');
```

But this returns `NULL`. Now I try to get it from the `$form`.

```
// Does contain a lot of stuff, but not the entered email address
$form->get('email');

// Does also contain a lot of stuff, but not the desired content
$request->get('email');
$request->request('email');

// Throws error message: No method getData()
$request->getData();
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really, really simple. You create a form with related entity. In FOSUserBundle you should have a `RegistrationFormHandler`, and in `process` method you've got:

```
$user = $this->createUser();
$this->form->setData($user);
if ('POST' === $this->request->getMethod()) {
     $this->form->bind($this->request);
     if ($this->form->isValid()) /**(...)**/
```

After the line `$this->form->bind($this->request)` every value in `$user` object is overwritten by data from form. So you can use `$user->getEmail()`.

On the other hand you are able to get data directly from request, but not by the property name, but by form name. In FOSUserBundle registration form it is called `fos_user_registration` - you can find it in `FOS/UserBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php` in `getName` method.

You get it by:

```
$registrationArray = $request->get('fos_user_registration');
$email = $registrationArray['email'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use Controller as a Service (which should work with this), you could pass the RequestStack (sf >=2.4) in the constructor and do `$this->request_stack->getCurrentRequest()->get();`

My guess is that you are trying to get the POST data. You are trying to put the data in a form object I presume. I would recommend you to take a look at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html if you have a custom form.

As regarding to your question, the form is probably containing a name. If you want to have direct access to it instead of doing things in your form, you need to fetch it multilevel if directly via the true at $deep, `get('registration_form_name[email]', null, true);` You can also do `$email = $request->get('registration_form_name')['email'];` (if you have php 5.4+)

Comment: It was hard to chose wheter to accept your answer or Piotrs, so I supported the answerer with lower rep. I apologize and thank you very much!